# C# Timeouts on Asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timeout

After making an Asynchronous Call in C#, I would like to be able to test for Timeouts so I won't wait indefinitely for an answer. Here is my code:

```
RemoteAsyncDelegate RemoteDel = new RemoteAsyncDelegate(obj.MethodHello);
// Call delegate to remote method
IAsyncResult RemAr = RemoteDel.BeginInvoke(null, null);
Console.WriteLine(RemoteDel.EndInvoke(RemAr));
```

Is there a way for `EndInvoke` to wait for a limited amount of time (Timeout)?

If not, is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following;

```
if(RemAr.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000)) // timeout value
{
   Console.WriteLine(RemoteDel.EndInvoke(RemAr));
}
else
{
   //throw exception etc.
}
```